# Unable to create new Java class in new package on IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

When i am creating new package in my intelliJ Idea for java it doesn't shows java class option after creating new package.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HyperSkill OOPS` is not a valid package name, because it contains spaces. Also, you can't use the keyword as a package name, for example as a package name, variable name, or class name. If you choose a different name for your package, the option to create a Java class should appear.

for learn about valid package names in java [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)